# Original non Steam 1.6 Keys/Download

Tags: counter-strike

I'm looking for a way to play CS 1.6 in LAN with computers that don't have permission to connect into Steam. It's really important that this version is a original/legal one.

Is there a solution for this? Any ideas?

Comment: Why can't those computers connect to Steam?

Comment: Proxy restriction.

Comment: Is this in a school?

Comment: We'll help you get the game working, but bypassing proxies and other security measures tend to be things we don't help with, I believe.

Comment: I'm not interested in any kind of bypassing any security/legal restriction..... I just want a original copy running in my machine.

Comment: @Koviko yeap. Problem? :)

Comment: Yes, it's a problem; a school has a proxy for a reason.  If you want to get it working, the answer is to ask your IT guy to open a hole for you, not bypass the security put in place to prevent exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: What part of "I'm not interested in any kind of bypassing" you didnt understand? My IT guy don't know where to find this so this is the reason i'm asking you. But if you dont want to help thats ok.

Comment: You have a proxy restriction.  You said so yourself.  You're trying to get around that.  That's bypassing security.  If your IT doesn't know how to open a hole so you can do this, well, then your IT guy needs to do some research so he can, not you get around the proxy.  That said, there might be a method to get CS running without a connection to Steam, but I bet the answer is to actually connect to Steam.

Comment: @adolfosrs I had a hunch.

Comment: I'm not trying to get around my proxy. I'm not trying to connect to steam. gl hf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not possible**. Counter-Strike 1.6 was released as an update through Steam. It was never released outside of Steam. Previous versions have seen retail releases, but 1.6 did not.

> The Steam client was first made available for public beta testing in January 2003 during the beta period for Counter-Strike 1.6, for which it was mandatory to install and use. [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam_(software)#Initial_release)

Comment: Thanks god there is someone with direct answers here. ^^

Comment: If you can find an older version of the game and are able to get it to work on the machine, it should work on the LAN unless they have the ports blocked.